# Installing Xen Hypervisor on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-installation, xen

I would like to try out the Xen Hypervisor and have been following this guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen

I'm stuck at the part about the partition.

How do I go about setting up the partitions correctly during the install of Ubuntu to get it ready for Xen?  I see that dom0 only needs to be 5-10gb.  During installation do I click "Something Else" and how do I make sure I'm using LVM?

Answer (score 3):

`dom0` really needs less then 4GB. During partitioning I recommend:

- manual
- root partition 4GB
- no swap partition
- leave the rest of the disk unpartitioned

Install the OS and then install XEN.

Add to `/etc/default/grub`the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN="dom0_mem=1024M,max:1024M dom0_max_vcpus=2"
```

Add a 512MB swap file in the local file system (e.g. `/var/swap`).

Partition the rest of the disk as you like. Ideally create another partition that fills up the disk, then use it as physical volume for LVM.